# CIDR to netmask conversion in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I found some code in PHP to convert CIDR to netmask.

```
function createNetmaskAddr($bitcount) {
   $netmask = str_split(str_pad(str_pad('', $bitcount, '1'), 32, '0'), 8);
   foreach ($netmask as &$element) $element = bindec($element);
   return join('.', $netmask);
}
```

Is it possible to do it in javascript?

Unfortunately I have no experience in javascript.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
function createNetmaskAddr(bitCount) {
  var mask = [], i, n;
  for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
    n = Math.min(bitCount, 8);
    mask.push(256 - Math.pow(2, 8-n));
    bitCount -= n;
  }
  return mask.join('.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function cidrToString(bits) {
  const netmaskText = (Math.pow(2, bits) - 1) * Math.pow(2, 32 - bits);
  const parts = netmaskText.toString(2).match(/.{1,8}/g);
  return parts.map((x) => parseInt(x, 2)).join('.');
}
> console.log(cidrToString(24));
255.255.255.0
```